# NGinx ldap "require group" doesn't work as expected

Tags: nginx, ldap, nginx-location

I am trying to use "require group" in extra ldap_server in order to achieve some ACL on Nginx and LDAP group level.

Given the below configuration I am logging in with a valid LDAP user who doesn't belong to mygroup but still can see content.

```
# nginx.conf

ldap_server myserver {
  url "ldaps://ip:686/ou=people,dc=company,dc=com?uid?sub?(objectClass=person)";
  binddn "uid=binduser,ou=internal,dc=company,dc=com";
  binddn_passwd "...";
  group_attribute "member";
  group_attribute_is_dn on;
  require valid_user;
  satisfy all;
}

ldap_server myserver-restricted {
  url "ldaps://ip:868/ou=people,dc=company,dc=com?uid?sub?(objectClass=person)";
  binddn "uid=binduser,ou=internal,dc=company,dc=com";
  binddn_passwd "...";
  group_attribute "member";
  group_attribute_is_dn on;
  satisfy all;
  # I have tried to put intentionally wrong/non-existing groups - no effect. Still can access.
  require group 'cn=mygroup1,ou=intgrp,ou=groups,dc=company,dc=com';
  require group 'cn=mygroup2,ou=intgrp,ou=groups,dc=company,dc=com';
}


# location_context.conf

# Tried to define on top level, didn't work with override ldap_servers. Moved to each location - still doesn't work.
# auth_ldap "Forbidden";
# auth_ldap_servers myserver;

location / {
    auth_ldap "Forbidden";
    auth_ldap_servers myserver;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}

location  /restricted_view {
    auth_ldap "Forbidden";
    auth_ldap_servers myserver-restricted;

    proxy_pass         http://backend:8080;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I haven't @swetad90